# SFDC Visualforce not rendering CSS styling

Tags: css, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to apply CSS styling rules to a Visualforce page. My ultimate goal is to generate a PDF from the page using the renderAs="pdf" (which is not included here because I am trying to isolate the problem).

I have tried creating an external stylesheet using the the various tutorials on developer.force.com pages without any success. These stylesheets were added to the SFDC via static resources as you can see from the code below. However the styling is not rendered.

I also tried apply inline styling to test and again this is not rendered.

I am testing in the Sandbox PRO in my org using API 33. I tried other API versions but got the same results.

Can anyone provide some clues on how to fix the issue

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
 <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.csstesting, 'qstyles.css')}"/> 

   <style type="text/CSS">
  @page {
 /* Landscape orientation */
 size:landscape;

 /* Put page numbers in the top right corner of each
    page in the pdf document. */
 @bottom-right {
 content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   }

 }
  </style>

 <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="standardBackground"/>
 <apex:outputText style="background-color:#0000FF"><span>Hello</span>               </apex:outputText>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce serves Visualforce pages as HTML4.01. I'm not a html/css expert, but I think those directives might be only available in HTML5. Try the following:

`<apex:page showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" docType="html-5.0">`

See this question on sfsx for more info: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4672/what-happens-if-i-use-html5-doctype-in-visualforce?rq=1